# Could serializer's to_representation generate multiple output items in DRF 3?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

In short, a serializer:

```
class ReleaseComponentContactSerializer(StrictSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    component = serializers.SlugRelatedField(source='release_component', slug_field='name',
                                             queryset=ReleaseComponent.objects.all())
    role = serializers.SlugRelatedField(source='contact_role', slug_field='name',
                                    read_only=False, queryset=ContactRole.objects.all())
    contact = ContactField()

    def to_representation(self, instance):

    ...........................
        # I hope return one dict or multiple dict, for first instance it return dict1, for second one it return dict2, dict3
        return ..............

    class Meta:
        model = RoleContact
        fields = ('id', 'component', 'role', contact)
```

I hope the results is something like dict1, dict2, dict3, NOT dict1, [dict2, dict3]. Is it possible? I think it is what I want.

The original question is I have three models,

```
class ReleaseComponent(models.Model):

    .................
    global_component            = models.ForeignKey(GlobalComponent)

    name                        = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contacts        = models.ManyToManyField(Contact,   through='contact.RoleContact', blank=True)

class RoleContact(models.Model):
    contact_role = models.ForeignKey(ContactRole, related_name='role_contacts',
                                     on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    contact      = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name='role_contacts',
                                     on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    global_component = models.ForeignKey('component.GlobalComponent', blank=True, null=True,
                                         related_name='role_contacts')
    release_component = models.ForeignKey('component.ReleaseComponent', blank=True, null=True,
                                          related_name='role_contacts')

class GlobalComponent(models.Model):
    """Record generic component"""
    .................................
    contacts        = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, through='contact.RoleContact', blank=True)
```

If ReleaseComponent don't have contact, it will use its GlobalComponent's contact. So one RoleContact object may be connected to multiple release components, because one RoleContact -> one GlobalComponent -> multiple ReleaseComponent. If ReleaseComponent have a contact and this contact don't share with GlobalComponent, then it must be one RoleContact -> one ReleaseComponent. Generally speaking, with picking queryset, one RoleContact -> one or more ReleaseComponent.

I hope the output format will be consistent. In output, each item corresponding to one ReleaseComponent's one RoleContact information. Even for the RoleContact object for multiple ReleaseComponent objects. I can generate multiple dicts in to_representation, but in final output, this multiple dict will be in a list, like

```
[dict2, dict3, dict4]
```

Is it possible to make them out of the list in final output? To be part of:

dict1, **dict2, dict3, dict4,** dict5, ........ ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output you are getting and how do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: I want to_representation to return maybe multiple dicts. I hope in final output these dicts not in a list. For example, for instance1 it return dict1, for instance2 it return dict2, dict3, I hope final result is [dict1, dict2, dict3], not [dict1, [dict2, dict3]].

Comment: Are you getting `[dict1, [dict2, dict3]]` as the output? I don't think you would be getting that output from DRF as it serializes multiple instances to return a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Yes, in my test it will return this. Simply make to_representation return {1, 2}, {2, 3}, it will generate result like [[ {1, 2}, {2, 3}], [ {1, 2}, {2, 3}]]. If it is impossible by using drf directly it's fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let me know if i have understood correctly. Lets say i am getting output `[d2,d3,d4]`. You want to insert another dictionary `d1` and `d5` in the list to get `[d1,d2,d3,d4,d5]` as the final output.

Comment: For you example, let's say in queryset we can get 3 objects, for obj1, 'to_representation' return d1; for obj2, return d2, d3, d4; for obj3, return d5, then the final result in response is [d1, [d2, d3,d4], d5]. What I expect result is [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5].  I found maybe could achieve this in view side by flatting the result. Maybe don't have to do something in serializer.

Comment: You need to do that in your views after getting `serializer.data`. Included a solution. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in your views after calling `serializer.data` to modify the serialized data as per your requirements.

You need to do something like:

```
serialized_data = my_serializer.data  # original serialized data
return_data = [] # final response which will be returned
for item in serialized_data:
    if isinstance(item, list): # check if a list inside serialized data
        return_data += item # add the elements of the list to 'return_data' list
    else:    
        return_data.append(item) # Otherwise just append the item to 'return_data' list
```

`return_data` contains the final desired response.